# How can I clear the current state of my providers manually in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-plugin

How can I clear the current state of my providers manually in my Flutter app? while I'm using **MultiProvider**

The use case I have is when a user signs out of my app then signs up as a new/different user the previous users' state is still stored in the providers.

it is cleared automatically when the app is restarted, however.

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: ServiceProvider().providers,
      child: Consumer<AppLocale>(builder: (BuildContext context, AppLocale locale, Widget? child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Application',
          localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          navigatorKey: RouteService.navigatorKey,
          scaffoldMessengerKey: RouteService.rootScaffoldMessengerKey,
          supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
          onGenerateRoute: Routes.generateRoute,
          initialRoute: RoutePaths.SplashScreen,
          onUnknownRoute: Routes.generateRoute,
          navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[AppRouteObserver()],
          locale: locale.appLocal,
          theme: appTheme(),
          // debugShowMaterialGrid: true,
          // showPerformanceOverlay: true,
          // checkerboardRasterCacheImages: true,
          // checkerboardOffscreenLayers: true,
          // showSemanticsDebugger: true,
        );
      }),
    )
```

Below is my ServiceProvider class

```
class ServiceProvider {
  final List<SingleChildWidget> _independentServices = <SingleChildWidget>[
    // ignore: always_specify_types
    Provider.value(value: null)
  ];

  final List<SingleChildWidget> _dependentServices = <SingleChildWidget>[];

  final List<SingleChildWidget> _uiConsumableProviders = <SingleChildWidget>[
    // ignore: always_specify_types
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AppLocale(),
    ),
    // ignore: always_specify_types
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => UserDetailsProvider(),
    ),
    // ignore: always_specify_types
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => AccountAddressProvider(),
    ),
    // ignore: always_specify_types
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => ServiceProvidersProductsProvider(),
    ),
    // ignore: always_specify_types
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => LookupValuesProvider(),
    ),
  ];

  List<SingleChildWidget> get providers {
    return <SingleChildWidget>[..._independentServices, ..._dependentServices, ..._uiConsumableProviders];
  }
}
```

Comment: Implement a function inside your provider class that deletes everything when logout is pressed.

Comment: you have to define a callback to clear the available data in your provider, you can also add more code for more specific answer